# model in bootstrap not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

here below is the code of bootstrap model but its not working

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta  charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width , initial-scale=1.0">
<title>bootstrap</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css">

</head>
<body>
                    <a href="#mymodel" class="btn" data-toggle="model">login</a>
        <div class="model hide" id="mymodel" aria-hidden="true" >
    <div class="model-header">
    <h1>Login</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="model-body">
    <form >
    <label>Email</label><input type="email" class="span3"></br>
    <label>Password</label><input type="password" class="span3"></br>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Login</button>
    <button type="reset" class="btn ">Clear</button>
    </form>
    </div>
    <div class="model-footer">
   <button class="close" data-dismiss="model" aria-hidden="true">close</button>
    </div>

</div>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>

      </body>
</html>
```

please help me in create a model in bootstrap i did alright but when ever click on login button its not appearing my model here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### first add bootstrap css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.css" />
```

#### add the model

```
<div class="modal hide fade" id="mymodel">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>
    <h1>Login</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <form >
        <label>Email</label><input type="email" class="span3"></br>
        <label>Password</label><input type="password" class="span3"></br>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Login</button>
        <button type="reset" class="btn ">Clear</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
   <a class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">close</a>
  </div>     
</div>
```

#### now add the `<a href` at required place

```
<a class="btn" data-toggle="modal" href="#mymodel">login</a>
```

#### now add required scripts

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

#### update:jsfiddle demo

http://jsfiddle.net/suhailvs/w5jRa/

Answer (score 4):

It's "**modal**", not "*model*". With an "**a**".

So you should have `data-toggle="modal"`, `data-dismiss="modal"`, etc.

Comment: +1 for `modal` that is how bootstrap will identity it is a modal